# How to use kartik select2 in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some select menu that are dynamically generated on my page, and i want to replace all the HTML5 select menu with kartik select2, in the image below the first select menu is a static one and i just put select2  in my php form in and the other are dynamic i generated them by clicking the add button, now i want to change the HTML5 select to kartik select2, how do i achieve this.
  [image]

```
function addColor(){
   var div = $(

    '<div class="col-md-offset-3 color2" style="padding-left:15px; border:1px solid red;">'+
        '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-md-5" >'+
                    '<div class=""><span class="text-muted">Color</span></div>'+
                   //'<div class="list-title-input"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter color!" ></div>'+
             $("select").select2({
```

tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true
  })+

```
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-md-5" >'+
                      '<div class=""><span class="text-muted">Color photo</span></div>'+
                      '<div class="btn btn-success fileUpload float-left" style="width:40px; height:35px;">'+
                            '<span ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></i></span>'+
                            "<input type='file' class='upload addPhoto' id='addPhoto'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
                      '</div>'+
                      //"<div class=\"color-image\"><img src="+url+name+" class=\"img img-thumbnail\"></div>"+
            '<div class="addMore" style="float:left; margin-left: 10px;"><a href="javascrip::void();">Add more</a></div>'+
            '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="remove" style="float:left; margin-left: 10px;"><a href="javascrip::void();">Remove</a></span>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
     '</div>'
     );
    $(".color1").append(div);
}
```

i want to change the select option in the code to kartik select2 i tried this way but no luck. I add the class select2 in my select tag and i add this code

```
 $("#id").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

please just change your js code

```
$(".common class").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true
});
```

Or

```
$("select").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but i try this before i only got jquery [object Object] instead of select box i don't know why?

Comment: Do one thing remove all the select2 option and add only function like below. 
 
$("select").select2();

Comment: i updated my question, i remove the select tag and add the function as u said but i get jquery [object Object]

Comment: @sam can you give me fiddle demo so I can under stand what is the actual error. and hope to possible to give you solution ??

Comment: Thanks for your below is the fiddle but it seems the code not working either https://fiddle.jshell.net/sammyzeal/h5pqx121/1/

Comment: Hey @sam please check below fiddle I hope you can find your solution in this.https://fiddle.jshell.net/khatrikiran/spkhhb8h/

Comment: I have done some changes so check this one latest  https://fiddle.jshell.net/khatrikiran/vpzxz8g5/ if you need any help please message me. :)